# redux-form: <FieldArray> + <FormSection> for complex arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using `redux-form` to try to create a form that results in an array of objects, such as:

```
const formData = {
  //...
  rules: [
    {
      level: 1,
      source: 'some source',
      //...
    }, {
      level: 3,
      source: 'another source'
      //...
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems like I should be able to next multiple `FormSection`s with a `FieldArray` component...but I can't make it work. Here's my current attempt:

```
const renderRules = ({ fields, meta: { error } }) => (
  <div>
    <Button
      text="Add Rule"
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fields.push()
      }}
    />
    {fields.map((rule, index) => (
      <FormSection name="rule"} key={index}>
        <legend>Rule {index + 1}</legend>
        <Field name="level" component={Select} label="Level">
            <Option value={1}>Level 1</Option>
            <Option value={2}>Level 2</Option>
            <Option value={3}>Level 3</Option>
        </Field>
        <Field name="source" component={Input} label="Source" />
      </FormSection>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

but this does not work :( as all the values get put under the `rule` key, not as an object within the `rules` array. Has anyone done this before? All the examples I can find of `FieldArray` only use a single `Field` element, but it's got to be possible to do something more complex. Has anyone done this before? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out & am posting for anyone else who comes up against this issue. Don't use a `FormSection` & use the `rule` argument when assigning the name of each field within the array, like so:

```
const renderRules = ({ fields, meta: { error } }) => (
  <div>
    <Button
      text="Add Rule"
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fields.push()
      }}
    />
    {fields.map((rule, index) => (
      <legend>Rule {index + 1}</legend>
      <Field name={`${rule}.level`} component={Select} label="Level">
          <Option value={1}>Level 1</Option>
          <Option value={2}>Level 2</Option>
          <Option value={3}>Level 3</Option>
      </Field>
      <Field name={`${rule}.source`} component={Input} label="Source" />
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

This gives the `Field` a name of `rule[0].limit` or `rule[0].source` & correctly nests the object within the array.